# combine two files -- one after another

Tags: unix, awk

Say, I have two files:
file1:

```
0
0
-3.44785
-2.15069
5.70183
17.8715
```

and file2:

```
31.9812
50.5646
72.361
96.8705
119.893
144.409
```

Two combine them side by side, I use :

```
paste -d" " file1 file2
```

or I use awk command to do such thing.

If I want to combine these two files one after another, what should I write? I know how to do this using "`cat`". I have tried different things  to modify the "`paste`" command but they don't give desired output. 
Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: define "combine". How should the output look like? because it seems like `cat file1 file2` should make it.

Comment: I exactly want the output as 'cat' command does. I was just curious how to modify the 'paste' command to get a similar output as using 'cat'

Comment: Using `paste` to `cat` doesn't make sense. Every tool has a way to work and `cat` is the simplest. Also, if you want `paste` for that, indicate so in the question, otherwise you made Marcus Muller lost the time by suggesting something you already knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would use `cat file1 file2`, but you could do it like:

```
awk '{print $0}' file1 file2
```

or

```
awk '1' file1 file2
```

(Note: the `'1'` does the the same thing as `print`)

Comment: Thank you. But I was wondering how one could possibly edit the 'paste' command to do so?

Comment: @user3389597: that's not paste's job. Don't use a comb to wire up your house, or a wall clock to mine for fish ;)

Comment: @user3389597 There are 2 options for paste `-d` (to specify the deliminator) and `-s` (to put the files serially). I can inefficiently do something like `paste -s file1 file2 | tr '\t' '\n'` ... but this would need converting the output of paste :T Not recommended~

Comment: Hi, csiu thanks.  Hi Marcus, thanks for your comment. I guess, it was a stupid attempt to use 'paste' for this job

Answer (score 3):

`cat` (short for concatenate) is your friend:

```
cat file1 file2
```

That's pretty basic; most people are aware of cat long before they learn to deal with `awk`, so kudos for mastering the latter!

Comment: Hi, I already know how to do this using "cat". But I was trying to modify the "awk" command. May be I should have edited my question.